# Conditional Formatting macro with key

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

Im trying to make a macro to conditionally format a column. So, that it will change the fill color for cells based on keywords contained in the cells i'm also trying to make it so that this macro will create a new sheet and output a key that only contains keywords and fill colors for keywords contained in the column that is being formatted.

So for example if I have a list of keywords that has 30 words and the column only uses 9 of the words in this case then it would output a key on a separate sheet that only contained the 9 used words along with the corresponding fill colors.

This is what the macro currently looks like, it will conditionally format the column and create a new sheet that outputs a key but it contains all keywords even when they are not used.

```
Sub ColorCoringPluskey()
'
' ColorCoringPluskey Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Color Coding Key"
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Word"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Color"
    Range("A1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("B1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Strategize"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Coordinate"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Committee"
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Attention"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Work"
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Criculate"
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Numerous"
    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Follow up"
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Attend" & Chr(10) & "Attend to"
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Attention to"
    Range("A12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Print"
    Range("A13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "WIP"
    Range("A14").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Prepare" & Chr(10) & "Prepare for"
    Range("A15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Develop"
    Range("A16").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Participate"
    Range("A17").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Organize"
    Range("A18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Various"
    Range("A19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Maintain"
    Range("A20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Team" & Chr(10) & "Team call"
    Range("A21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Address"
    Range("B2").Select
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 13.43
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 31.43
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10053120
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B3").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13421619
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16777062
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Sheets("Fees").Select
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Strateg", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10053120
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Coordinate", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13421619
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Committee", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16777062
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Attention", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 2162853
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Work", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5263615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Circulate", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10066431
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("Color Coding Key").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 2162853
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B6").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5263615
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B7").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10066431
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B8").Select
    Sheets("Fees").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Numer", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13158
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Follow Up", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="atten", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Print", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092543
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("Color Coding Key").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13158
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B9").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 39372
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B11").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092543
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B11").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B12").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092543
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Sheets("Fees").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="WIP", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13056
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Prep", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 32768
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="develop", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 3394611
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("Color Coding Key").Select
    Range("B13").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13056
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B14").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 32768
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B15").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 3394611
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B16").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092441
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Sheets("Fees").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Particip", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10092441
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Organize", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13369548
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Various", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16751103
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("Color Coding Key").Select
    Range("B17").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13369548
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B18").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16751103
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B19").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16724787
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B20").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16750950
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B21").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 6697881
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Sheets("Fees").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Maintain", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16724787
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Team", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16750950
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="address", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 6697881
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Sheets("Fees").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  Note that it's not finding "Attention to" because it finds "Attention" first.  To be successful, order them in the order of priority for finds (higher the list get found first), or make sure you aren't going to have duplicate partial matches like that.

```
Sub ColorCoringPluskey()
'
' ColorCoringPluskey Macro
'

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsKey As Worksheet
    Dim wsFees As Worksheet
    Dim aKeyColors(1 To 20, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim aOutput() As Variant
    Dim sKeyShName As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsFees = wb.Sheets("Fees")
    sKeyShName = "Color Coding Key"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsKey = wb.Sheets(sKeyShName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wsKey Is Nothing Then
        Set wsKey = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
        wsKey.Name = sKeyShName
        With wsKey.Range("A1:B1")
            .Value = Array("Word", "Color")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
    Else
        wsKey.Range("A2:B" & wsKey.Rows.Count).Clear
    End If

    aKeyColors(1, 1) = "Strategize":    aKeyColors(1, 2) = 10053120
    aKeyColors(2, 1) = "Coordinate":    aKeyColors(2, 2) = 13421619
    aKeyColors(3, 1) = "Committee":     aKeyColors(3, 2) = 16777062
    aKeyColors(4, 1) = "Attention":     aKeyColors(4, 2) = 2162853
    aKeyColors(5, 1) = "Work":          aKeyColors(5, 2) = 5263615
    aKeyColors(6, 1) = "Circulate":     aKeyColors(6, 2) = 10066431
    aKeyColors(7, 1) = "Numerous":      aKeyColors(7, 2) = 13158
    aKeyColors(8, 1) = "Follow up":     aKeyColors(8, 2) = 39372
    aKeyColors(9, 1) = "Attend":        aKeyColors(9, 2) = 65535
    aKeyColors(10, 1) = "Attention to": aKeyColors(10, 2) = 65535
    aKeyColors(11, 1) = "Print":        aKeyColors(11, 2) = 10092543
    aKeyColors(12, 1) = "WIP":          aKeyColors(12, 2) = 13056
    aKeyColors(13, 1) = "Prepare":      aKeyColors(13, 2) = 32768
    aKeyColors(14, 1) = "Develop":      aKeyColors(14, 2) = 3394611
    aKeyColors(15, 1) = "Participate":  aKeyColors(15, 2) = 10092441
    aKeyColors(16, 1) = "Organize":     aKeyColors(16, 2) = 13369548
    aKeyColors(17, 1) = "Various":      aKeyColors(17, 2) = 16751103
    aKeyColors(18, 1) = "Maintain":     aKeyColors(18, 2) = 16724787
    aKeyColors(19, 1) = "Team":         aKeyColors(19, 2) = 16750950
    aKeyColors(20, 1) = "Address":      aKeyColors(20, 2) = 6697881

    wsFees.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    ReDim aOutput(1 To UBound(aKeyColors, 1), 1 To 2)
    With wsFees.Columns("G")
        For i = LBound(aKeyColors, 1) To UBound(aKeyColors, 1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & aKeyColors(i, 1) & "*") > 0 Then
                j = j + 1
                aOutput(j, 1) = aKeyColors(i, 1)
                aOutput(j, 2) = aKeyColors(i, 2)
                .FormatConditions.Add xlTextString, String:=aKeyColors(i, 1), TextOperator:=xlContains
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = aKeyColors(i, 2)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If j > 0 Then
        wsKey.Range("A2").Resize(j, 1).Value = aOutput
        For i = 1 To j
            wsKey.Cells(i + 1, "B").Interior.Color = aOutput(i, 2)
        Next i
        wsKey.Columns("A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: for some reason its only highlighting the words Committee and Team, the collum that im using the macro on currently uses almost every keyword but it only highlights+gives a key for those two words, any thoughts?

Comment: I tested and verified it was working so I know that the code is correct. Try checking the spelling in your column G

Comment: Only 2 words are being conditionally formatted:   
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOq0b.png

Comment: for example all of the cells in this picture contain the word "attend" but none of them are being formatted https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtEnx.png

Comment: @HaydenShirts Found a minor bug in the `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf` line that was causing the issue.  Updated its criteria argument to have the * on both sides and verified it should now work properly given your provided sample data.  Updated answer to reflect the change.